# Ubuntu processes stop working

Tags: ubuntu, process

I have a script written in python that executes a whole bunch of processes in a predetermined order.  It uses the following function to execute those processes.

```
ON_POSIX = "posix" in sys.builtin_module_names

def executeCommand(cmd):
    print cmd
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX, shell=True)
    p.communicate()
```

However, sometimes when these processes are executed the function never returns and just sits there forever.  The child processes are not listed in top or ps aux | grep .  Any idea why these processes are not returning?

PS I'm running this from a service that I installed myself.  Also, I've tried running them from a python Pool (threadpool) and without that (it happens both in the threadpool and when run individually).